# DT column filter destroys shiny navbar input elements

Tags: r, filter, shiny, navbar, dt

I have a shiny app in which a new tab panel with input element gets created by a click of a button. There is also a DT object which shows global information and with which elements can be selected and modified with another button (not relevant in example).

The point is: when I activate the column filter in the DT-object, the input elements in the created tab panel get somehow destroyed.

My app has already multiple layers and to work around is not easy, maybe someone has an answer to this.

[example of added tab without filter in DT-object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANdUb.jpg)

[example of added tab with filter in DT-object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAcsw.jpg)

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title = "Test"
             , id = "tabs"
             , tabPanel("test_panel",
                        mainPanel(
                          actionButton("button_new_tab", "New tab", width = "20%"))
                        , DT::DTOutput("testtable", width = "100%"),
                        width = "100%"
             )
  )
  
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("a","B","c"))
  

  
  observeEvent(input$button_new_tab, {
    
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs", tab = tabPanel("added_tab",
                                               
                                               sidebarLayout(
                                                 sidebarPanel(
                                                   tabPanel("test tab",
                                                            selectizeInput("inp_field", "Test data"
                                                                           , choices = c(a = "a", b = "b", c = "c")
                                                                           , multiple = TRUE))),
                                               
                                                   mainPanel()
                                                 )
                                               )
              )
    
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs",
                      selected = "added_tab")
  })
  
  
  
  output$testtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(data
             # , filter = 'top'    #### comment or uncomment here
              )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A workaround in this example would be to create the appendTab outside the observeEvent() and hide it. On button click it can be "activated" via showTab(). This would work for this usecase, but this is just a minimal example and my app is complicater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour due to a Javascript error `Error: Unable to find "selectize-plugin-a11y" plugin` which can occur if you use a DT with `filter` option.

This is at least similar to a known problem which is currently listed as an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3125) on GitHub. However, as discussed there (see the link), a workaround is to include an `htmltools::findDependencies` on your `selectizeInput` into your `ui`. Minimal example below.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
    title = "Test"
    ,
    id = "tabs"
    ,
    tabPanel(
        "test_panel",
        mainPanel(
            htmltools::findDependencies(selectizeInput(
                "inp_field", "Test data"
                , choices = c(a = "a", b = "b", c = "c")
            )),
            actionButton("button_new_tab", "New tab", width = "20%")
        )
        ,
        DT::DTOutput("testtable", width = "100%"),
        width = "100%"
    )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "B", "c"))
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$button_new_tab, {
        appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                  tab = tabPanel(
                      "added_tab",
                      
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                          tabPanel(
                              "test tab",
                              selectizeInput(
                                  "inp_field",
                                  "Test data"
                                  ,
                                  choices = c(a = "a", b = "b", c = "c")
                                  ,
                                  multiple = TRUE,
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                      
                      mainPanel())
                  ))
        
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs",
                          selected = "added_tab")
    })
    
    
    
    output$testtable <- renderDT({
        datatable(data
                  , filter = 'top')
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for ur fast reply and answer. This community here is awesome. Thanks again!